# Problem with url routing in Zend Framework, needs index.php?

Tags: php, zend-framework, indexing, url-routing

As you may know a Zend link should look like this: **mydomain.com/index/user** for controller index and action user or **mydomain.com/category** for controller category and action index. But for me in most web hostings I have to use **mydomain.com/index.php/category** or else it won't find any page at all. It's like it doesn't find it's way in to the indexfile.

My code:

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$router = $frontController->getRouter();
$router->addRoute('category', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('category/:pid', array('controller' => 'category', 'action' => 'index')));
```

so.. mydomain.com/index.php/category/1 works,
mydomain.com/category/1 doesn't even find a page.. I'll be very thankful for your help.

Comment: mod_rewrite enabled? .htaccess created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the documentation on the standard router which includes a set of mod_rewrite rules which you can place in an .htaccess file in the root directory and which will rewrite requests for mydomain.com/category/1 as a request for mydomain.com/index.php/category/1

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

Comment: Thanks.. I got it to work with the tips from KingCrunch an a little help from http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.rewrite.html :)